# fetchone is returning only the last item in my table?

Tags: python, sqlite

Question from a noob learning python and sqlite.

I have created table Phrase which contains 50 items (id, phrase).

I want to recover each row from the table in turn and use the data for further processing. i.e
recover (1, phrase1)from row 1 and process, then recover (2, phrase2) from row 2 and process, etc.

when i run my code i get only the last item from the table.

```
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Phrase WHERE phrase = ? ', (phrase, ))
phrase_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(phrase_id, phrase)
```

**Output**

```
50 leadership
```

*(where these are the index and phrase50 respectively)*

what am I doing wrong?  why does it not return the first row?  advice on how do adjust my code to cycle through all rows in turn?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be in a specific order, you have to use `ORDER BY` to specify the order you want.

```
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Phrase WHERE phrase = ? ORDER BY id', (phrase, ))
```

Comment: still returns me only row 50; same output as original.

Comment: Then 50 must be the first ID containing that phrase.

Comment: You're only selecting a specific phrase, not every phrase in the table, because of `WHERE phrase = ?`

Comment: So you're only going to get the id of the `leadership` phrase, since that's what you asked for.

Comment: When i view my table in SQLite i see 50 rows, with id and phrase as the column headers.  row 1 is 1/the, row 2 is 2/of, ..., row 49 is 49/innovation and row 50 is 50/leadership.  my code seems to pick up only row 50.

Comment: "only going to get the id of the leadership phrase, since that's what you asked for"; I thought i was asking for whatever phrase was in the row.  i must be misunderstanding the syntax.

Comment: What do you think `WHERE phrase = ?` means? You specifically asked for the row with `phrase = 'leadership'`